# JQuery: How to not join specific field in .submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form

```
<form action="GET" id="form">
....
<input type="text" name="a" value="aaa">
<input type="text" name="b" value="bbb">
<input type="text" name="c" value="ccc">
<button ... value="go" id="submit">
....
```

is it possible that I can prevent the `input name="b"` not to be join in the `.submit()` ? the whole input `<input type="text" name="b" value="bbb">` not to be submitted?

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Comment: try remove the name from it.

Comment: you want to never submit it or just once in a while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable it.

```
jQuery('[name=b]').prop("disabled", true);
```

… and it won't be a successful control.

Answer (score 0):

The form will submit all the fields which have a name. So if you omit the name tag from an element that will not be submitted.

```
<form action="GET" id="form">
....
<input type="text" name="a" value="aaa">
<input type="text" value="bbb">
<input type="text" name="c" value="ccc">
<button ... value="go" id="submit">
....
```

This way only a and c will be submitted.